# Adding a "position" number in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I got the following query and result currently:

```
mysql> SELECT songname,COUNT(*) as count FROM etrstats WHERE songname != '' AND `when` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)  GROUP BY songname ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5;
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| songname                             | count |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| Meghan Trainor - All About That Bass |    67 |
| The Cars - Drive                     |    55 |
| Train - Drops Of Jupiter             |    54 |
| C.W. McCall - Convoy                 |    52 |
| The Script - Superheroes             |    48 |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
```

What I want to do is add a second, temporary field to the query that shows which position it is after the sort.
So the result would look like this:

```
+-----+--------------------------------------+-------+
| Pos | songname                             | count |
+-----+--------------------------------------+-------+
| 1   | Meghan Trainor - All About That Bass |    67 |
| 2   | The Cars - Drive                     |    55 |
| 3   | Train - Drops Of Jupiter             |    54 |
| 4   | C.W. McCall - Convoy                 |    52 |
| 5   | The Script - Superheroes             |    48 |
+-----+--------------------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @x = 0;
SELECT (@x:=@x+1) Pos,* FROM
(
    SELECT songname,COUNT(*) as count FROM etrstats
    WHERE songname != '' AND `when` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    GROUP BY songname ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
) A;
```

Give it a Try !!!

I do incrementing of temp variables in other posts

- `Jun 08, 2012` : [Update rank on a large table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/update-rank-on-a-large-table/18990#18990)
- `Jun 03, 2013` : [Embedded select with rank](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43661/embedded-select-with-rank/43684#43684)

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for, though had to make a slight change to it(could perhaps be that I'm on MySQL 5.5?) MySQL didn't like the Pos,* FROM, had to change that to Pos,songname,count FROM.